# PowerShell: Need to search content of several different file types for certain string and display name + path

Tags: shell, powershell

I want to search a folder the the recurse subfolder's files for a certain string (e.g. "Banana"). I can't seem to get it to work...

This is what I got:

```
$Searchstring='Banana'
$PathArray=@()
$Path='C:\users\myuser'
$content= Get-Content $_.FullName 

 Get-ChildItem $Path | 
  Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"}

      ForEach-Object ( 
         If ($content | Select-String -Pattern $Searchstring) {
           $PathArray += $_.FullName

         }
      )
```

unfortunately, this script does not do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution:

```
$SearchInDirectory = "C:\SearchingFolder";
$SearchForString = "Banana"; #String for searching
$SearchInFormats = "*.asp", "*.txt", "*.js"; #If empty will search in all file formats

echo 'Searching in progress...'
Get-ChildItem  $SearchInDirectory  -include $SearchInFormats   -recurse  |  Select-String  -pattern  $SearchForString  -SimpleMatch  |  group path  |  select name
```

It searches (recursively) in all directories and sub-directories for all the results and then prints them, so if you have a lot of files and directories it may take some time. Also, you can specify the file types you need to check (but not necessarily).

And also, I have a script that puts the results into file:

```
$SearchInDirectory = "C:\SearchingFolder";
$SearchForString = "Banana"; #String for searching
$SearchInFormats = "*.asp", "*.txt", "*.js"; #You can specify the file types
$PutSearchResultsInFile = ""; #link to a file or if blank - the results to be displayed on screen

Cls;

function SearchFilesByString_results () {
    Get-ChildItem  $SearchInDirectory  -include $SearchInFormats   -recurse  |  Select-String  -pattern  $SearchForString  -SimpleMatch  |  group path  |  select name
}

if($PutSearchResultsInFile){
        if(!(Test-Path -Path $PutSearchResultsInFile)){
           New-Item $PutSearchResultsInFile -itemType "file" -confirm:$false | Out-Null 
           echo "`nNew file created. `n";
        } 
        echo "Searching in progress... `n";
        SearchFilesByString_results > $PutSearchResultsInFile;
        echo "Search completed! Find results here: " $PutSearchResultsInFile "`n";
} else {
    echo "`nSearching in progress.... `n";
    SearchFilesByString_results
    echo "`nSearch completed! `n";
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not updateing the `$content` which you are using to search. 
Also, you can simplify this:

```
$Searchstring='Banana'
$Path='C:\users\myuser'

$PathArray = Get-ChildItem $Path -File | Select-String -Pattern $Searchstring | select -ExpandProperty Path
```

Comment: You don't need the ForEach loop, You can piple the Get-Childitem directly into Select-String like so: `Get-ChildItem $Path -File | Select-String -Pattern $Searchstring | select -ExpandProperty FileName`

Comment: @DaveSexton Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This shows only the file names, while the guy wants to see the path too. You can add that too :)